# Trying to import a STC file into SAS

Tags: import, sas, dataset

I am a student new to sas working on a desktop provided by my University. I am trying to import a STC file into SAS 9.4, but am having trouble. I have tried simply right-clicking on the file, and then clicking open with SAS 9.4, and have also tried using code which you can find below:

```
    proc cimport
        infile = 'C:\Users\jmistry\Downloads\tildastc.stc'
        lib=work;
     run;
```

Regardless of the method, I get a warning from sas that "no data is available." Any reason why sas is not picking up the datafile?

and right-clicking on file and opening with sas 9.4

Comment: If this is a SAS transport file use the approach listed here https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_042/movefile/n0bnkhnx5f0d77n1ht8vff23udta.htm

Comment: Hi, yes, this did not work. The error continues to say that there is no data available

Comment: What's the size of the STC file? Also, please show the code and the log.